# how to deliver data to other ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
@IBAction func hallOfFame(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let hof = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HOF") as? HallOfFameTableViewController else { return }
    hof.hallOfFames = self.hallOfFames.sorted(by: <)
}
```

Self-view has hallOfFame and it is Array.
And hof-view also has hallOfFame.
So I Send self-view's hallOfFame -> how-view's hallOfFame.
but hof-view do not receive data.
what's wrong?

Comment: Heard about segue ? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Comment: you can pass the data via segue or via delegate methods.

Comment: oops. selfVC & hofVC connected navigation Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want send the data forward in the view controller stack, you can use perform segue and prepare for segue method
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw&t=595s

but if you send the data backward, you can use protocol and delegate pattern : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhqXUi1SF4s&t=198s